# Decoding Dict in Elm failing due to extra backslashes

Tags: json, decode, elm

I'm trying to send a `dict` to javascript via `port` for storing the value in localStorage, and retrieve it next time the Elm app starts via `flag`.

Below code snippets show the dict sent as well as the raw json value received through `flag`. The Json decoding fails showing the error message at the bottom.

The issue seems to be the extra backslashes (as in \"{\\"Left\\") contained in the raw flag value. Interestingly, `console.log` shows that the `flag` value passed by javascript is `"dict1:{"Left":"fullHeightVerticalCenter","Right":"fullHeightVerticalCenter","_default":"fullHeightVerticalBottom"}"`as intended, so the extra backslashes seem to be added by Elm, but I can't figure out why. Also, I'd be interested to find out a better way to achieve passing a dict to and from javascript.

```
import Json.Decode as JD
import Json.Encode as JE

dict1 = Dict.fromList[("_default", "fullHeightVerticalBottom")
                        , ("Left", "fullHeightVerticalCenter")
                        , ("Right", "fullHeightVerticalCenter")]

type alias FlagsJEValue =
   {dict1: String}

port setStorage : FlagsJEValue -> Cmd msg

-- inside Update function Cmd
setStorage {dict1 = JE.encode 0 (dictEncoder JE.string model.dict1)}

dictEncoder enc dict = 
   Dict.toList dict 
     |> List.map (\(k,v) -> (k, enc v)) 
     |> JE.object 
-- 
type alias Flags =
   {dict1: Dict String String} 

flagsDecoder : Decoder Flags
flagsDecoder =
    JD.succeed Flags
     |> required "dict1" (JD.dict JD.string)

-- inside `init`
case JD.decodeValue MyDecoders.flagsDecoder raw_flags of
   Err e ->
      _ = Debug.log "raw flag value" (Debug.toString (JE.encode 2 raw_flags) )
      _ = Debug.log "flags error msg" (Debug.toString e)

      ... omitted ...

   Ok flags ->
      ... omitted ...


-- raw flag value
"{\n  \"dict1\": \"{\\\"Left\\\":\\\"fullHeightVerticalCenter\\\",\\\"Right\\\":\\\"fullHeightVerticalCenter\\\",\\\"_default\\\":\\\"fullHeightVerticalBottom\\\"}\"\n}"

 --flags error msg

"Failure \"Json.Decode.oneOf failed in the following 2 ways:\\n\\n\\n\\n
(1) Problem with the given value:\\n    \\n    \\\"{\\\\\\\"Left\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"fullHeightVerticalCenter\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Right\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"fullHeightVerticalCenter\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"_default\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"fullHeightVerticalBottom\\\\\\\"}\\\"\\n    \\n    Expecting an OBJECT\\n\\n\\n\\n

(2) Problem with the given value:\\n    \\n    \\\"{\\\\\\\"Left\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"fullHeightVerticalCenter\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"Right\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"fullHeightVerticalCenter\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"_default\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"fullHeightVerticalBottom\\\\\\\"}\\\"\\n    \\n    Expecting null\" <internals>”
```

Comment: I don't Elm, but the value reported in the error is a valid JSON where `dict1` was also JSON-encoded. `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(yourString).dict1)` produces the correct value. Are you sure you're not double-encoding JSON somewhere?

Comment: Unless  `(JE.encode 2 raw_flags)` somehow modifies the value of raw_flags, there is no encoding of the received flag values. Without JE.encode, raw_flags evaluates to `<internals>`, making it difficult to see exactly what was received.

Comment: You are right. `JE.encode 0` in `JE.encode 0  (dictEncoder JE.string model.dict1)` wasn't necessary. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to post the answer (I can't, Elm is all trees for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `JE.encode` there.

You can just use your `dictEncoder` to produce a `Json.Encode.Value` and pass that directly to `setStorage`.

The problem you're encountering it that you've encoded the dict to a json string (using `JE.encode`) and then sent that string over a port and the port has encoded that string as json again. You see extra slashes because the json string is double encoded.